# Count occurrences of a character within a string when outside square brackets

Tags: php, sql, regex

**Short Version:**

How to count the number of `@`'s in a string whilst excluding `@`'s inside `[ ]`'s

**Longer Version:**

I'm writing a simple php class to allow the use of `@NamedSqlParameters` with `sqlsrv_query()` (I realise this is already possible using `PDO_SQLSRV` - but as I understand it, `PDO_SQLSRV` is only available in windows environments - This class is for a Debian environment using the MS SQL Linux driver).

When a user passes in an array of `@NamedParamaters`, I need to check the `$CommandString` contains an equal number of `@NamedParamaters`, initially I though id get away with using `substr_count()` to count the number of `@`'s but that would obviously not take into account non-parameter related `@`'s - take an example `$CommandString`:

```
SELECT * FROM [@foo] WHERE ID = @ID AND BAR = @BAR
```

So yea, How would I count the number of `@`'s in a string whilst excluding `@`'s inside `[ ]`'s

I suspect `preg_match_all` will be needed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$s = 'SELECT * FROM [@foo] WHERE ID = @ID AND BAR = @BAR';
if ( preg_match_all('/\[[^]]*\]|(@)/', $s, $m) ) {
   $count = count(array_filter($m[1]));
   echo $count; // 2
}
```

Comment: Its cleaver :-) you have an extra space between `$` and `s`

Comment: Thanks, mistake fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the trick `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to skip parts between square brackets:

```
$pattern = '~\[[^]]*](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|@~';

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
```

`(*SKIP)` forbids a substring to be retry if the pattern fail later
`(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail

Comment: Im not sure, but I don't this is handling multiples correctly, for example, it returns 1 on the following: `SELECT * FROM [@foo] INNER JOIN [@bar] ON whatever = whatever WHERE ID = @ID AND BAR = @BAR AND WOOF = @WOOF` - either way, anubhava's answer works great :)

Comment: @SabujHassan: It is simple, You try to match content inside square brackets first (to be sure that the second part of the alternation find only `@` that are not inside brackets). `(*SKIP)` is a backtracking control verb that forces a substring to not be retry by the regex engine when the subpattern on the right fails. `(*FAIL)` make it fail.

Comment: @HeavenCore: I have forgotten to put `[0]` after `$matches`!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Another creative solution of yours!!! Hey you probably know this, but you don't need to `count($match[0])`. That's because `preg_match_all()` returns the number of matches, so you can say `$result = preg_match_all(etc)`